# Would my downloaded Ubuntu, require an Internet Conncetion?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, live-usb, iso

I downloaded a setup of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS of about 600 MB (don't remember the actual size) and burned it on a USB using unetbootin. 
So, is that Ubuntu the "offline installer"? 
I can't run an online installer as I have a Broadband with a speed of 256 kbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standalone installer that you plug into your USB port and then boot your computer from the USB drive. It contains all of the basic stuff to install a complete, working Ubuntu system.

According to [the installation instructions on the website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support), they recommend you stay connected to the Internet so you can receive updates as you're installing. This ensures that your system will be up to date after installing. However, it isn't required.

Once fully installed, you'll still need to connect to the Internet and update all of the packages, and you'll need to do this frequently in order to continue to keep the software up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Their standard installer does not *require* an Internet connection, it simply recommends one.

Personally even with really good speeds, I tend to keep my machines offline till the install is finished, then boot, then update. I like that process better, but it's all taste.

TO install without network access just don't get on the internet. It will install fine, and you won't have any more updates to do over time then if you installed with internet access. The main difference is do you do the updates during install, or do you do them post install. That is totally a user preference.